# imagescale to a new width and keep quality and aspect ratio

Tags: php

I need to scale all images inside a folder (`images323`);
all images have width smaller then `960px`
they should have a new width - `960px` - and keep the `quality` and `aspect ratio`.

I'm getting error: - `imagescale() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given`

```
$arr = glob('images323/*.jpg');
foreach($arr as $el){
    imagescale($el, 960, -1); // error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that you are passing a string to [imagescale](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale) function, [imagescale](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale) function require the first parameter to be a resource, which is a file handle

so you code should be like:

```
$arr = glob('images323/*.jpg');
foreach($arr as $el){
    $handle = imagecreatefromjpeg($el);
    imagescale($el, 960, -1); // error
}
```

Note that I'm using [imagecreatefromjpeg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) because you are scanning for JPEG images, for PNG, use [imagecreatefrompng](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)

Comment: what is `rb`, pls?

Comment: This is by mistake, I removed it, this function only takes  the image file path.